# Accuracy mismatch in tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, image-classification

I am working on image classification project. I have trained model on car dataset. So it gives good accuracy but when I predict BMW car with my model it gives below results.

BMW :- 98%
Audi :- 91%

Why Audi labels shows 91% it should be low. How to solve this issue? I am using resnet 50 pre trained model.

Comment: it can happen, more than one label may be plausible, simply choose the largest predition

Comment: I found a solution that we should use the softmax activation function. previously I used the sigmoid activation function.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that we should use the softmax activation function in the last layer. previously I used the sigmoid activation function